# Angular ViewChildren not retrieving children drawn by *ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular, viewchild

I am passing templateRef from one component to another and want to access the component drawn inside the wrapper component

```
<wrapper [template]="myTpl"></wrapper>

<ng-template #myTpl>
  <hello></hello>
  <hello></hello>
</ng-template>
```

I want to access HelloComponent inside the wrapper component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'wrapper',
  template: `
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"></ng-container>
  `
})
export class WrapperComponent {
  @Input() template: TemplateRef<any>;

  @ViewChildren(HelloComponent)
  set comps(val: QueryList<HelloComponent>) {
    console.log('setter in wrapper ', val.length);
  }  
}
```

But its always 0.

If i try to access the same in app.component.ts i get the value!!
how can i access HelloComponent inside wrapper component?

code available at - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gtwcx7